The problem with the Aiogram, Docker and event loop
I have a bot manager written in Aiogram 3 and an asynchronous parsing function is running in the manager. When I run this code on my PC, everything works, but when I deploy to Docker, the error "This event loop is already running" pops up. Apparently there is some kind of problem with Docker, but I can't figure out what because DockerFile is written correctly and works correctly.
from parser_main import run_parser
from src.config.cfg import bot, dp
from src.handlers import basic
from src.config.timer import timer_db
from src.handlers.basic import start_parsing_for_active_users

import multiprocessing
import logging
import asyncio


def run_parser_wrapper():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(run_parser())


async def on_startup():
    print("The bot is running")
    # Starting the asynchronous timer function, start_parsing, starting the parser
    asyncio.create_task(timer_db())
    asyncio.create_task(start_parsing_for_active_users())
    parser_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_parser_wrapper)
    parser_process.start()


async def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format="%(asctime)s - [%(levelname)s] - %(name)s"
                               "(%(filename)s).%(funcName)s(%(lineno)d) - %(message)s"
                        )
    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
    dp.startup.register(on_startup)
    dp.include_routers(basic.router)
    try:
        await dp.start_polling(bot)
    finally:
        await bot.session.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

DockerFile
FROM python:3.11.5

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app/

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app/

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["python", "manager.py"]

I have checked all the calls to asynchronous functions in other files and have found nothing that could be causing the issue, everything works fine on the PC.
